# Sort file based on information from different file

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file (f1) that contains two columns; f1 looks as follows:

```
bob population1
sam population1
jen population2
amy population2
jim population3
bob population3
doc population4
allison population4
zoe population5
karla population5
```

In a different file (f2), I specify how I would like individuals in f1 to be sorted based on their population; f2 looks as follows:

```
population4
population1
population2
population5
population3
```

I am looking for the following outcome:

```
doc population4
allison population4
bob population1
sam population1
jen population2
amy population2
zoe population5
karla population5
jim population3
bob population3
```

Could anyone please give me advice on how to achieve this outcome?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow; please, tell with more details what you want to achieve; do you want shell scripting (then tag your question with more precise tags like "shell" or "script")? Anyway, you have to tell what you already tried and what didn't work as you expected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the lines from f2, extract the matching lines from f1 for each one:

```
while read s ; do
    grep "$s" f1
done  < f2
```

Or, without a loop, some variation of

```
nl f2 \
| sed 's=\([0-9]\+\)\t\(.*\)=s/\2/\1 \2/=' \
| sed -f- <(nl f1) \
| sort -nk3,3
```

i.e. number the lines in both files, replace the "populationX" with its corresponding number, then sort by the numbers.